# Manipulating times on excel

Tags: excel, time

I have a sheet with my employee names listing all the jobs they have done in a month. It contains the start time, and completion time and the format is hh:mm.

I then have a formula that subtracts start time from finish time to give me the total time spent on each job. the service we run is 24/7 so sometimes they start jobs before midnight and complete them after so the formula I created to take this in to account and not have errors with negative times was this one:
=IF(V6>R6,V6-R6,24-R6+V6)   (R is started time, V is completed time). again the number format is hh:mm

The issue I am now having is trying to average the time per job, as it now counts any cells with 00:00 as a 24hr long job and is skewing all the averages.

Any advice on how I should format these numbers, should I keep them in decimal the whole way until the final figures, or is there a better formula for subtracting times from each other without leaving zero time jobs as 00:00?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the table like this:

```
Employee  Start  End   | Total (Formula = IF(...))
==============================
Foo bar   19:00  08:00 | 13:00
Foo bar   09:00  13:15 | 04:15
Foo bar   10:00  15:30 | 05:30
Foo bar   21:00  11:45 | 14:45
==============================
               Average:  09:23 (Formula = AVERAGE(...))
```

Change the condition from `V6>R6` to `R6<V6`:

```
IF(R6<V6,V6-R6,24-R6+V6)

09:00 & 13:15 ==> 04:15
19:00 & 08:00 ==> 13:00
00:00 & 00:00 ==> 00:00
```

The zero-duration jobs would still be included in the average though, if you're okay with that.

Comment: Sorry i should have given more info, theses jobs are alloctaed to the stafs handhelds, some are already done or dont come through correctly with a start time, so we have a few that are zero duration, but with my current formula it treats these as 24hrs long. Is there a better way to subtract times across the 00:00 mark without leaving zero time duration jobs as 00:00.

Comment: Check my edit. Let me know if that's what you're looking for. Should the zero-duration jobs be included in the average?

Comment: just deleted and correct my last comment, the issue i am having is not zero duration jobs but rather jobs where the is no start time recorded, so the formula tried to deduct 0 from 24 and give me a 24 result. Is there a better way to subtract times that cross the midnight barrier. I am thinking if i merge the Start date and start time columns and do the same for the completed then i can subtract without a fancy formula and if i have no data in either column it wont return a 24 result?

Comment: In general, two ways: use the full time incl. date (hence no matter how many days in between) or leave empty cells just empty, don't write 00:00 in (and exclude such empty cells).